# Maths in stretched cells

Tags: tables, math-mode, height

Here is a minimal working example of my table :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.866,0.894,0.996}

\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{myblue}}p{#1}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{tabular}{ B{0.2\textwidth} | B{0.2\textwidth} }
title column 1 & title column 2 \\ \hline
content & content with binomial coefficient $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have used `\arraystretch` to increase the height of the rows of my table. The problem is that, when I write a binomial coefficient in a cell using `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}`, the parenthesis are too large. The command `\arraystretch` seems to affect the environment `pmatrix`. How can I keep the row height and have a binomial coefficient which looks nice ?

Moreover, `\arraystretch` modifies the space between and after the text in *all* the cells. How can I modifiy this space locally, for one given row ?

Comment: Why you not use `\binom{n}{k}` instead `\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}`? On it `arraystretch` doesn't has influence.

Comment: @Zarko : Thank you for the advice ! I didn't know `\binom`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.866,0.894,0.996}
\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{myblue}}p{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{50pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{tabular}{ B{0.2\textwidth} | B{0.2\textwidth} }
title column 1 & title column 2 \\[50pt] \hline
content & content with binomial coefficient  {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt} $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}$} \\ [50pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Since you need the distance above the `\hline` to be equal to that below it, you should add `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{50pt}` to control the distance above and add `\\ [50pt]` with the same value `50pt` to control the distance below.

To cancel the effect within a math array, just issue the command `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}` to neutralize the previous setting. Alternatively, you can apply @Zacro's advice and use `\binom{n}{k}` instead of `\begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix}`. The latter does not get affected by `\extrarowheight`.

Comment: Thank you ! I have solved my problem by ending each line (except the last one) of the table with `\rule{0pt}{1cm} \rule[-1cm]{0pt}{0cm} \\ \hline`. This allows me to set a blank space before and after each line. However, one cell contains `\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{content1 \\ content2}` to force a linebreak in a cell. If I end the corresponding line with `\rule{0pt}{1cm} \rule[-1cm]{0pt}{0cm} \\ \hline`, I get an enormous blank space before the horizontal `\hline`. Do you know where this is coming from?

Comment: I solved this issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Take care, though, your solution will not work for multi-line cells.

Comment: I think it works, even for multi-lines cells : I replaced `\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{content1 \\ \content2} \rule{0pt}{1cm} \rule[-1cm]{0pt}{0cm} \\ \hline` with : `\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{ \content1 \rule{0pt}{1cm} \\ content2 \rule[-1cm]{0pt}{0cm} } \\ \hline`. This would work even if I had two line-breaks inside `\parbox`. I would have to put `\rule{0pt}{1cm}` before the first \\ and `\rule[-1cm]{0pt}{0cm}` before closing the parbox. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the factor inside the table cells:

```
\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{myblue}}p{#1}}
```

so that the value of 2 is only used at the outer level.

> Moreover, \arraystretch modifies the space between and after the text in all > the cells. How can I modifiy this space locally, for one given row ?

if you just want to change one row, do not change `\arraystretch` anywhere, leave it as 1, and just use `\\[5cm]` to have extra space after the spacial row.

Comment: Thank you ! In my table, each row ends with `\\ \hline`. If I use `\\[1cm]` instead of \\, it will increase the space before the horizontal rule. What I would like is to equally increase the space before the rule and after the rule (if there is another row after this one). Something like : `\\[1cm] \hrule \vspace{1cm}` does not work.

Comment: put `\rule{0pt}{5cm}` at the start of the next row after `\hline` in that case.